# Как заинклюдить файл из другой папки?

Tags: php

Есть файл, расположенный по адресу papka1/papka1/file1.php. 
В этом файле есть инклюд другого файла, из другого каталога: 
include('../papka2/papka2/file2.php');
Но почему то сайт, при выполнении file1, выдает ошибку:

> Warning:
> include('../papka2/papka2/file2.php')
> [function.include]: failed to open
> stream: No such file or directory in
> papka1/papka1/file1.php
>
> Warning: include() [function.include]:
> Failed opening
> '../papka2/papka2/file2.php' for
> inclusion
> (include_path='.:/usr/local/php52/lib/php')
> in papka1/papka1/file1.php

Как это исправить и сделать, чтобы был нормальный инклюд?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разберитесь с относительными путями, вам надо на 2 уровня подняться:

```
../../papka2/papka2/file2.php
```

Comment: спасибо, не знал про это...